# Passing messages to indirect related actors

Tags: java, scala, concurrency, akka, message-passing

What is the best way to pass messages to indirect related actors? Let's say I have 5 actors where each actor is a child of the prior actor (the parent), and actor #2 has multiple children. How would actor #5 at the bottom layer (Actor #1 would be at the top in this example) be able to sufficiently pass a message to one of Actor #2's indirect related children?

Sketch below: Arrow pointing at child actor representing the message

Now I get that the actor selection mechanism here would work but according to the official Akka documentation, it should be avoided unless you're making use of remoting. So, would it be best to simply somewhere hold a global singleton reference to Actor #1 and pass the message down from there? What if this chain gets even more complex? Am I forgetting about some wicked design pattern to go around this?

If a similar question to this was answered before, I'd appreciate it if you could link me to it as I could not find it.

To be specific, I am currently using Akka in Java. Scala based solutions are also welcome.

[image: child actor]

Answer (score 3):

I would not have a problem with using Actor Selection in this case, however the docs does state that it is preferrable to avoid Actor Selection when refs can be used. If you are sending many messages from Actor #5 to the same child in this way, you could use Actor Selection up front to get an ActorRef with `resolveOne` and then use that ActorRef for subsequent communication. Maybe a reasonable compromise.

If you don't want to use Actor Selection, I would not use a global singleton, but rather make the actorRef part of the constructors of Actors 3, 4, and 5 so that the reference is passed down to Actor 5. I think the same documentation which warns against Actor Selection gives the answer to the alternatives:

> In all other cases ActorRefs can be provided during Actor creation or
>   initialization, passing them from parent to child or introducing
>   Actors by sending their ActorRefs to other Actors within messages.

One more alternative, is to use a publish and subscribe mechanism: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/event-bus.html

If the child actor has subscribed to a channel, Actor #5 can publish messages to the channel without needing to know the identity of the subscriber.

Comment: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.13/java/untyped-actors.html#Identifying_Actors_via_Actor_Selection

"It is always preferable to communicate with other Actors using their ActorRef instead of relying upon ActorSelection. Exceptions are

sending messages using the At-Least-Once Delivery facility
initiating first contact with a remote system"

Comment: Thanks. TBH, I think the same part of the docs gives you the best answer "In all other cases ActorRefs can be provided during Actor creation or initialization, passing them from parent to child or introducing Actors by sending their ActorRefs to other Actors within messages."

Comment: That sucks :/. I was honestly hoping for a better solution for Akka to provide.

Comment: I haven't looked into events yet so I'll definitely take a look at that. From what you've described so far, I like it.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 ways:

1. Pass child's `ActoRef` in constructor to #5 actor.
2. Have another actor as a "receptionist" which will hold a list of needed `ActorRef`s and will send them as reply to some asking message.

Comment: I don't really like having to pass down that same actor reference down the chain multiple times. It could break semantics in a complex architecture where services are isolated and loose-coupled. I somewhat like the 2nd solution more but it's not completely what I'm looking for.

Comment: if you want isolated and loose-coupled services, I think you should use actorSelection